# Is it possibleto Start a Flash video with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, flash

I'm using html5 as a video player but as it doesn't work in ie8 and we have to support ie8 im using a fallback to flash.  I need the videos to swap from one to another on click which i have got to work for both the html5 video player using .load and the flash player by replacing the html in a div but I need the video to start to play.

In html5 it works as follows:

```
                    $(".featureLogoText").on("click", function (event) {

                        $oVideo[0].pause();
                        $oPause.hide();
                        $oPlay.hide();
                        $oPlay.css('display', 'block');

                        var media = $(this).attr('media');
                        var mediamp4 = media + "mp4";
                        var mediawebm = media + "webm";
                        var mediaogv = media + "ogv";
                        var newPoster = $(this).attr('data-poster');
                        $('.scrPoster').attr('poster', newPoster);
                        $('.scrVideomp4').attr('src', mediamp4);
                        $('.scrVideowebm').attr('src', mediawebm);
                        $('.scrVideogg').attr('src', mediaogv);
                        $(".scrPoster").load();

                        var html = ' <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"352\" height=\"198\" flashvars=\"src=' + mediamp4 + '&poster=' + newPoster + '\"></embed>';

                        $("#objFlash").html("");
                        $("#objFlash").append(html);

                        var number = $(this).attr('data-number');
                        alert(number);

                        $oVideo[0].play();
                        $oPlay.hide();
                        $oPlayBig.hide();
                        $oPause.css('display', 'block');
                    });
```

How can i do the same thing with flash? is it possible? Or is there a better way to show video across browser incl ie8 - i've looked at videojs but it says that doesn t support ie8.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strictly dependent on the type of flash player you choose to use.

some have an API that allow to programatically play the video.

In example. the common player [FlowPlayer](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/) has such a command:

```
// get a handle to the first player on the page and start the clip
$f(0).play();

// get a handle to the first player and stop it
$f().stop();
```

Short answer: Yes.

Comment: I think i ll need to look into flowplayer i m currrently using http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf i'm afraid i dont  kow a hige amount about fladsh